# Get last update date for iOS application

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'd like to display to the user when my app was last updated. On android I say:

```
PackageInfo p = a.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(a.ApplicationInfo.PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
TextView lastUpdated = messageView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lastUpdated);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
lastUpdated.Text = "App Updated on " + dt.AddMilliseconds(p.LastUpdateTime).ToLocalTime().ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

How can I do something similar for iOS?

Comment: iOS does not keep the last update time on its bundle like Android does. You will need to either write it manually to your plist with a run script phase or keep a server with the last update time which the app will check against.

Answer (score 1):

from the below itune app search api you can get your app details.
 http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=yourBundleID&country=appCountry

simple download the file from the url at runtime and read the data as json string, now in obtained result you can get your current version release date from key `currentVersionReleaseDate`

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about exact time of installation (when app is downloaded and extracted by App Store app on the device), you could inspect file/folder attributes within your app bundle.

The following command:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath)
```

gives you a list of attributes of app folder. You can alternatively try to get attributes on main executable file to track updates between app launches for instance, if it gives you some useful data.